# Sticky Notes : Displaying reminders on home screen

Tags: android

I have developed an application which stores reminders and to do list activities.
Now i want the to do activity of the day, say 'collect laundry' to be displayed on my home screen.
How can one approach that? (Must not be notifications)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).